# No matching object on query during save() override on model - DoesNotExist error thrown

Tags: python, django

I'm overriding my Model save() to check and see if there is a Consumer (related object) that already exists with the email entered. When a Consumer does exist with a matching Email, the code executes as expected and associates the Case to the correct Consumer. However, if there is not an existing Consumer that exists with a matching Email, I'm receiving the error: "DoesNotExist: Consumer matching query does not exist."

I've tried adjusting the save() method, however to me it looks correct (obviously, could be wrong here).

Models.py

```
class Case(models.Model):
  ...

  def save(self,*args,**kwargs):

    if Consumer.objects.get(email__iexact=self.email):
        self.consumer = Consumer.objects.get(email__iexact=self.email)

    else:
        consumer = Consumer(first_name=self.first_name,last_name=self.last_name,email=self.email)
        consumer.save()

    return super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

The expected results is to create a new Consumer object in the case that the Email entered on the Case does not match an already existing Consumer's email. Instead, it throws this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your:

```
if Consumer.objects.get(email__iexact=self.email):
    # ...
```

will raise an error, given no such `Consumer` object exists, or there exists multiple ones.

You can however just check if no such object exists, and create one if it is missing, with a single [**`.get_or_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) call:

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.consumer, __ = Consumer.objects.get_or_create(
        email=self.email,
        defaults={'first_name': self.first_name, 'last_name': self.last_name}
    )
    return super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

So in case there is already a `Consumer` for that `email`, we just retrieve it, otherwise we create it and retrieve it. We then set the response to `self.consumer`, and save the object.

Note however that it is not very safe to do that: `.save(..)` can be overruled, for example in a [**`.bulk_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). Furthermore here you make a copy of the data. If later update your `Case` object, it will no longer be in sync.

Comment: You can also use `Consumet.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.email).exists()` to check for existence.

Comment: @ryan28561: yes, but then you make two calls, and some databases can optimize an "*upsert*".